# WebView2 control unable to render html

Tags: c#, wpf, webview2

I'm testing `WebView2 (1.0.774.44)` to see if it can replace old IE embedded web browser for my wpf project. What I'm doing is **simply navigate to wherever the domain** I hardcoded. And it works fine on my Dev environment. But when I test my app (the same .exe) on one of my virtual machines, it does not work.

On the testing environment, the web viewer only displays blank pages. When I run *DevTools* on the page, it looks like it loads html strings. I can even click links or buttons on the page. I just cannot see them.

There are not much to share either. I just simply made a new window that is declared like below.

```
//TestWebViewWindow.xaml
<window 
...some declarations
    xmlns:wv2="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf;assembly=Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf"
...more declarations
>

    <Border>
        <wv2:WebView2 Name="xWebView" Source="https://microsoft.com">
            <wv2:WebView2.CreationProperties>
                <wv2:CoreWebView2CreationProperties UserDataFolder="C:\Temp\webview2"/>
            </wv2:WebView2.CreationProperties>
        </wv2:WebView2>
    </Border>
</window>
```

At first, I thought it was a browser problem but then the problem persisted on my testing VM, even when I installed the latest compatible Webview2 Runtime.

Both of my testing and dev environment have `WebView2 Runtime (89.0.774.68)` installed. And I have copied `WebView2Loader.dll` on the testing environment.

Any guidance?

**EDIT**: I have not tried Disabling one of Display adapter, but unfortunately, that option is not a way I'm trying to pursue. What I found so far is that, stated problem does not seem to reproduce on latest release of Windows 10.

Comment: You must copy the whole `Release` folder to your VM, not just the exe and `WebView2Loader.dll. The `WebView2` use all files in that folder.

Comment: @PoulBak When I build the app, there are only executable binary with pdb and a folder named `runtimes` which contains `WebView2Loader.dll`. I copied them to the VM as well. Still not working.

Comment: Hmm, on my computer there are 7 files + 'runtimes' folder (for a minimal project with `WebView2`), don't know why you only have 2. Another thing: Are the host and the VM both 64 bit (or both x86)?

Comment: @PoulBak Yes. They are running under the same system architecture.

Comment: Does `C:\Temp\webview2` get created? Otherwise it could be a security issue.

Comment: @PoulBak Yes. I found another interesting point. The rendering process seems to be working on my other testing VM. Notable difference between two testing environment is that they are under the different version of Windows 10(1703 vs 1809). Not sure that makes the difference though.

Comment: Hmm, Windows 10 version 1703 sounds suspiciously old! Try upgrading it to 20H2 (make a backup first so you can go back, if something goes wrong). Or may be first try to install Microsoft Edge Chromium - I don't think that's installed on 1703.

Comment: @PoulBak I thought `Microsoft Edge WebView2 Runtime` was responsible for execution.  Are you suggesting to install MS Edge Chromium, then try targeting the new Edge executable path when I call `CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync`?

Comment: Was the chromium runtime properly installed on the virtual pc? I don’t know what is involved with that.

Comment: See here ... https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/1118

Answer (score 0):

The same problem here,
Finally I found a solution by **disabling** one of my display adapters and changing the **main display** in Windows settings.

As a less aggressive method, you can also try to change the main monitor on Windows

It's completely odd but it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

We experienced a similar issue and finally discovered that it could reproduce only whenever we worked with **more than one graphics card adapter**. Perhaps it's also your case.